# Using facebook's javascript sdk to login to a django site

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm trying to find a way to allow users to log into my django website using the facebook login button. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) I've found a way to login with OAuth, but I cannot find a way to have the facebook login button to use OAuth instead of the SDK, or to hook the SDK into one of the django social auth apps.

I've tried several of the top auth plugins, and they either don't work at all or only use OAuth and don't support the login button.

Answer (score 1):

I think that login through the facebook javascript SDK would not be able to set any session info on the django backend . DO be able to complete the django login process you will have to do that as well.

Could you possibly make an ajax request in the callback of javascript login and run the django backend login code such that you are also able to set django session info .

I should warn you this may not work at all because of CORS .

Comment: I think what I might do is take the auth.login event and in there send  an ajax or open an invisible iframe to my oauth page. That should hopefully accept the auth from the javascript login.

Comment: Basically, we want the faces to show up of your friends that use the app. Currently, I just have an oauth button. Any way that gets me the faces works for me. RIght now I'm thinking of putting the fb login button in but overlaying the top part with my oauth button.